# (kivy) How can I do this without using empty data in RecycleView?

Tags: python, sqlite, kivy, scrollview

I have a problem, where I'm trying to display only two columns of information from my database, and the rest should only be blank TextInputs. At the moment the program looks like the one in the example pictures below. I'm trying to have the same result as in the picture, but right now the empty fields are made using "empty" data.

**main.py**

```
def get_players_koti(self, joukkue_nimi):
        connection = sqlite3.connect("poytakirja.db")
        cursor = connection.cursor()


        if not joukkue_nimi == '': 
            cursor.execute("""SELECT joukkue_id from joukkueet WHERE nimi = ?""", (joukkue_nimi,))
            joukkue_id = cursor.fetchone()[0]
            print(joukkue_id)

            cursor.execute("""SELECT pelinumero, nimi FROM pelaajat WHERE joukkue_id = ? ORDER BY pelinumero ASC""", (joukkue_id,))
            rows = cursor.fetchall()
            rows_kopio = rows
            listaus_settings = []

            for x in rows_kopio:
                listaus_settings.append(list(x))

            for y in listaus_settings:
                for _ in range(12):
                    y.append('')

            print("koti"+str(rows))
            data = []
            low = 0
            high = self.total_col_headings - 1
        # Using database column range for populating the TextInput widgets with values from the row clicked/pressed.
            self.data_items_koti = []
            for row in listaus_settings:
                for col in row:
                    data.append([col, row[0], [low, high]])
                low += self.total_col_headings
                high += self.total_col_headings
        # create data_items
            self.data_items_koti = [{'text': str(x[0]), 'Index': str(x[1])} for x in data]
```

**page.kv**

```
<PoytakirjaScreen>:
    name: "Poytakirja"
    on_enter:
        root.get_jengit()
        root.get_players_koti(self.kotinippu1)
        root.get_players_vieras(self.vierasnippu1)


    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        spacing: 10

        GridLayout:
            padding: [100,0,200,0]
            size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 50
            cols: 6
            Label:
                text: "Sarja:"
                size_hint_x: 0.1
            TextInput:
                id: sarja
                size_hint: (.35, None)
                height: 30
                multiline: False
                write_tab: False
            Label:
                text: "Ott.nr:"
                size_hint_x: 0.1
            TextInput:
                id: ottnro
                size_hint: (.1, None)
                height: 30
                multiline: False
                write_tab: False
            Label:
                text: "Alkoi:"
                size_hint_x: 0.1
            TextInput:
                id: alkuaika
                size_hint: (.1, None)
                height: 30
                multiline: False
                write_tab: False
            Label:
                text: "Paikka ja pvm"
                size_hint_x: 0.1
            TextInput:
                id: paikkapvm
                size_hint: (.30, None)
                height: 30
                multiline: False
                write_tab: False
            Label:
                text: "Yleiso:"
                size_hint_x: 0.1
            TextInput:
                id: yleiso
                size_hint: (.1, None)
                height: 30
                multiline: False
                write_tab: False
            Label:
                text: "Paattyi:"
                size_hint_x: 0.1
            TextInput:
                id: paattymisaika
                size_hint: (.1, None)
                height: 30
                multiline: False
                write_tab: False

        GridLayout:
            size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 50
            cols: 1
            Label:
                text: "Vieras"

        GridLayout:
            size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 20
            cols: 14
            Label:
                text: "Pelaajanumero"
            Label:
                text: "Nimi"
            Label:
                text: "Maali"
            Label:
                text: "Maalintekija"
            Label:
                text: "Syottaja 1"
            Label:
                text: "Syottaja 2"
            Label:
                text: "Pelaajanumero"
            Label:
                text: "Nimi"
            Label:
                text: "Maali"
            Label:
                text: "Maalintekija"
            Label:
                text: "Syottaja 1"
            Label:
                text: "Syottaja 2"
            Label:
                text: "Syottaja 1"
            Label:
                text: "Syottaja 2"



        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            RecycleView:
                viewclass: 'TextInput'
                data: root.data_items_vieras
                RecycleGridLayout:
                    cols: 14
                    default_size: None, dp(26)
                    default_size_hint: 0.1, None
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    multiselect: True
                    touch_multiselect: True


        GridLayout:
            size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 50
            cols: 1
            Label:
                text: "Koti"

        GridLayout:
            size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 20
            cols: 6
            Label:
                text: "Pelaajanumero"
            Label:
                text: "Nimi"
            Label:
                text: "Maali"
            Label:
                text: "Maalintekija"
            Label:
                text: "Syottaja 1"
            Label:
                text: "Syottaja 2"

        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            RecycleView:
                viewclass: 'TextInput'
                data: root.data_items_koti
                RecycleGridLayout:
                    cols: 14
                    default_size: None, dp(26)
                    default_size_hint: 0.1, None
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    multiselect: True
                    touch_multiselect: True
```

Is it possible to add these empty TextInputs without any data in RecycleView, or do I have to use some other method? Basically I'm just trying to fetch the number and the name information from SQLite, and display the connected number and name on its own row, and after that have blank fields you could fill out yourself. And is it possible to actually get the information, as in if it would be just a normal TextInput, so I could do a query where I add the information placed in the fields into the database?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tBBi.png)

[Example2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56rUQ.png)